# Fetching emails from Gmail as mbox format in Zend Mail

Tags: php, gmail, zend-mail, mbox

I am working on an email project using Zend Mail. I have successfully fetched all folders of Gmail with emails and attachments. But I cannot figure out how to download emails as mbox format? Do I need to use file handling to create mbox or there is an another way to download emails as mbox format?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google's Takeout for Gmail capability to download a copy of your email in MBOX format:

- All supported services (see "Mail"): https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout
- Gmail: https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout/custom/gmail

If you want to use the email and attachments you've already downloaded (e.g. using IMAP or POP), you can create a MBOX file by concatenating individual emails with attachments in MIME ([RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)) format, prefixing each message with a mbox separator line beginning with "From ". This header should be preceded by a blank line and not followed by a blank line. More information is available in [RFC 4155](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4155):

- IETF RFC 4155: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4155

Comment: Would you please add an example of creating a `MBOX` file for already downloaded email via `POP/IMAP`.